# Cada vez que recargo mi app se hace un POST

Tags: mysql, sql, nodejs, reactjs, express

me gustaria una ayuda con este problema:
Tengo una simple webapp creada con react en el frontend y node js-express para el backend, la app muestra un formulario que contiene dos areas de texto y un boton para submit, y el backend para manejar las entradas y hacer el respectivo query para que los datos se agreguen a la base de datos, el problema es que doy cuenta de que cada vez que cambia el estado de los inputs de area realiza el query de insercion, lo que hace que se creen un monton de filas en la bd, esto a pesar de que la funcion que lo hace solo se activa al hacer click en el boton

Este es el app.js react:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios'
import './App.css';


function App() {

  const [movieName, setMovieName] = useState("")
  const [review, setReview] = useState("")
  const submitReview = () =>{
    Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/insert', {
      movieName: movieName, 
      movieReview:review}
      ).then(()=>{
        alert('Insercion exitosa')
      })

  }


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Apliación CRUD</h1>

      <div className="form">
        <label htmlFor="moname">Nombre de la pelicula</label>
        <input type="text" name="movieName" onChange={(e)=>{
          setMovieName(e.target.value)
        }}/>

        <label htmlFor="moreview">Review</label>
        <input type="text" name="review" onChange={(e)=>{
          setReview(e.target.value)
        }} />

        <button onClick={submitReview()}>Enviar</button>

      </div>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

y este es el index.js del servidor:

```
const express = require('express')
const mysql = require('mysql')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()

const db = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'lola',
    database: 'crud-database'
})
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
// app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))



app.post('/api/insert', (req, res) => {
    const movieName = req.body.movieName;
    const movieReview = req.body.movieReview;

    const sqlInsert = 'INSERT INTO movie_reviews (movieName, movieReview) VALUES (?,?)'
    db.query(sqlInsert, [movieName, movieReview], (err, result) => {
        console.log(result)
    })
})

app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log('Corriendo en el puerto 3001')
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifica esto:

```js
        <button onClick={submitReview()}>Enviar</button>
```

por esto:

```js
        <button onClick={submitReview}>Enviar</button>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!, se solucionó!